# On the extension of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $u\in C^n([0,1])$, where $n$ is an integer. Show that for $\forall \delta>0$ there exists an linear operator $E_{\delta}$, such that

1. $E_{\delta}u=u$ a.e. in $[0,1]$.
2. $E_{\delta}u\in C^n(\mathbb{R})$
3. $\operatorname{supp}(E_{\delta}u)\subset[-\delta,1+\delta]$, where "$\operatorname{supp}$" denotes the support of the function.

---

How to generate this operator? My idea is to use the mollification, that is 
$$\phi_{\delta}(x)=\rho_{\delta}\star \chi_{[0,1]},$$
where $\rho_{\delta}$ is the mollifier, $\star$ is the convolution,
$$E_{\delta}u=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 &\phi_{\delta}(x) u &\quad\mbox{ if $x\in [0,1]$,}
 \\ &\phi_{\delta}(x)u(1) &\quad\mbox{ if $x\in [1,1+\delta]$,}
\\ &\phi_{\delta}(x)u(0) &\quad\mbox{ if $x\in [-\delta,0]$,}
\\& 0&\quad\mbox{ else.}
       \end{array} \right.$$
But this mollification cannot give $Eu=u$ a.e. How to modify this? Or is there some other technique to solve the problem ?Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I'd say there is an error in your requirements.

Comment: @GEdgar What is the error? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I misread 3, your conditions are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend $u$ to $\mathbb R$ by its Taylor polynomial in $0$ and $1$. Then multiply with a smooth cut-off function.